# Dynamic radio/checkbox solution in Aurelia

Tags: checkbox, binding, radio-button, aurelia

I have a gist demonstrating my problem here:

https://gist.run/?id=e2ccd5925e383f2fc36ad277c31bcf23

The checkbox version works fine, if you remove a check, it updates the model right, but if you change the selected radio button, it will keep the true value on the radio that got it's selection removed. If I remove the `model.bind="true"` value, it will write "on" instead of true. I do want true/false, and not on/off.

I want the object to get it's property updated to be a true or false depending on if it's chosen or not, dynamically. In my scenario I don't know how many radio buttons or checkboxes will need to be selected. I only know that in the cases of it not being a collection, I only want one, and in the case that it is a collection, I want an unknown number selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answer mentions - `<input type="checkbox">` behavior is different from `<input type="radio">`.

I have forked your gist and made the following changes to make your scenario with the radio button work in aurelia:

1) Added a function to the first object in your `params` collection called `selectedChanged`(it doesn't have to be there, could be on the viewmodel class instead, perhaps a better place for it). It is responsible for handling selection change in the radio button group, specifically it will iterate over a collection of `options` (second parameter), and set `selected` property to `true` on the option who's `id` matches the first parameter of the function, and to false on all other options.

2) There is an event on the `input` called `change`, I delegate it to a function called `selectedChanged` mentioned above, passing the `option.id` value and `options` as parameters.

https://gist.run/?id=5f38414fde799dfc145fc1291d9f2fd3&sha=f12283b08bfb45e77b8280d46a3709b6ccb82768

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve (turning individual value on/off) is not achievable with radio, as the way it works (select a single value out of a set) is different with check-box (turning individual value on/off) ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)). So If you truly want to have radio like appearance, with check-box behavior, consider employing some CSS and extra DOM elements to make it look like so, and behave like so.